# guidelines to build a multicolumn menu

Tags: c#, jquery, css, visual-studio-2010

I am working in a Visual Studio 2010 environment and I am looking for the most effective way to build a multicolumn list that will be displayed inside a jQuery Menu like:

[image: Multi column Menu]

I actually use a serverside DataList control that renders me a table with a RepeatColumns="3" attribute.
I would like to know the most efficient, frequently, most common technique to use for this purpose. I just look for guidelines :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to render the content as show - it makes no difference whether it's inside a jQuery dropdown menu, or straight on a static page.

You can do this using a table or using CSS, depending on which you're more comfortable with. The DataList control renders - as you say - to a table, which presumably works fine. A lot of people will say that you should use straight CSS rather than a table, but for this example the content is fairly 'tabular' in nature so I don't see a problem with using a table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one of the problems with the table is that if you change the margins of let's say the Categories (in my example) via the CSS, the height of the hole line will be impacted... And using only CSS, I didn't find any easy and proper way to split my list into X columns (elements arranded vertically)

Comment: This can be done without tables. I googled for 'wrappable columns with CSS' and found this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: I aleady read that very interesting page but the techniques described are ok for static content. My list will vary during the time, that's why i was looking for a way of implementing that (using DataList control, or in the page you specified technique n°2) that don't need to modify the CSS each time the list is modified.
The most common way to do that is probably to calculate server-side le number of elements divided by the number of columns wanted, then assign the proper <div> for each column...
But I just "suppose" it has to be done that way, I wanted the devs community's feedbacks :)